# Parse Structopt flag from anywhere in the input

Tags: rust, structopt

I would like to be able to have 'universal' flags in my command line tool, which uses [`StructOpt`](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.22/structopt/). That is, if I have a flag (such as `--debug`) I want it to behave the same regardless of where that flag is in the input:

```
$ mycli --debug alpha
$ mycli alpha --debug
```

(`alpha` and `--debug` are simply useful placeholders in this example; actual subcommands and flags would be different.)

Actual behavior:

```
$ cargo run -- --debug alpha                                                                                               nford 14:36:32
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/scratch-rust --debug alpha`
Debug mode enabled!
Alpha subcommand selected.
$ cargo run -- alpha --debug                                                                                               nford 14:36:27
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/scratch-rust alpha --debug`
error: Found argument '--debug' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    scratch-rust alpha
```

Expected Behavior:

```
$ cargo run -- --debug alpha                                                                                               nford 14:36:32
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/scratch-rust --debug alpha`
Debug mode enabled!
Alpha subcommand selected.
$ cargo run -- alpha --debug       
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/scratch-rust --debug alpha`
Debug mode enabled!
Alpha subcommand selected.
```

This is my `main.rs` code:

```
use std::str::FromStr;
use structopt::StructOpt;
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind};

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
/// Specific task being executed; one task might imply others, depending on flags.
pub enum Subcommand {
    Alpha,
    Omega,
}

impl FromStr for Subcommand {
    type Err = Error;
    fn from_str(subcommand_input: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match subcommand_input {
            "alpha" => Ok(Subcommand::Alpha),
            "omega" => Ok(Subcommand::Omega),
            _ => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Unrecognized subcommand.")),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(
    name = "Minimal Example CLI",
    about = "A minimal example of multi-location command line inputs.",
)]
pub struct CLIOpts {
    /// Set logging to verbose mode.
    // short and long flags (-d, --debug) will be deduced from the field's name
    #[structopt(short, long)]
    pub debug: bool,

    #[structopt(subcommand)]
    pub cmd: Subcommand,
}


fn main() {
    let args = CLIOpts::from_args();
    if args.debug {
        println!("Debug mode enabled!");
    }
    match args.cmd {
        Subcommand::Alpha => println!("Alpha subcommand selected."),
        Subcommand::Omega => println!("Omega subcommand selected."),
    }
}
```

This is my `Cargo.toml` file (the above example won't work w/o the `structopt` dependency):

```
[package]
name = "scratch-rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
structopt = "*"
```

Is there a way to do this without replicating the 'universal' flags at every level of subcommand?

Comment: I don't know about structopt, but it is based on clap, and clap has a `global` flag to make arguments behave the way you want. I assume that structopt has an attribute that reflects this flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clap has a [`global()`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.global) method for arguments that does what you want. You can access this method vis Structopt using [raw attributes](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.22/structopt/#raw-methods):

```rust
pub struct CLIOpts {
    /// Set logging to verbose mode.
    // short and long flags (-d, --debug) will be deduced from the field's name
    #[structopt(short, long, global = true)]
    pub debug: bool,

    #[structopt(subcommand)]
    pub cmd: Subcommand,
}
```

(note the added `global` attribute for `debug`)

The application now works the way you want it to:

```
$ cargo run -- --debug alpha
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running `target/debug/scratch-rust --debug alpha`
Debug mode enabled!
Alpha subcommand selected.
$ cargo run -- alpha --debug
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running `target/debug/scratch-rust alpha --debug`
Debug mode enabled!
Alpha subcommand selected.
```